# Polymer get property of object returned by filter

Tags: javascript, filter, polymer

I have a javascript array with a lot of object, like so:

```
var myArray = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Name 1",
        "active": false
    },{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Name 2",
        "active": true
    },{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Name 3",
        "active": false
    }
]
```

I use the `id` parameter of these objects to compare them and store values. To get the object that belongs to that id, I have written a filter:

```
getTest: function(id){
    var result = this.tests.filter(function(o){return o.id == id;} );
    return result ? result[0] : null;
}
```

So I can easily use this filter inline. Now I'd like to get properties of the filtered result inline as well, for example:

```
<template if="{{ { id | getTest }.active">
    You are active!
</template>
```

However doing this leads to an invalid expression. I've read through the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html) multiple times, but don't quite see if this is even possivle.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom filter with an id parameter. That filter will take the item, verify if it has the good id, and the verify if it's active or not.

My original example was in this Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/FSwzndyjRxJIymehsZIg?p=preview

Hope it helps! If it isn't exactly what you wanted to do, please ask, I'll try to answer further :)

[EDIT]

OK, after reading your comments, how about this:

```
  <template is="auto-binding">

  <h1>Hi !</h1>
   <template repeat="{{item in myArray}}">
      <template if="{{ item.active }}">
        <p>
        Item id:{{item.id}} is active! <br>
        Amount of steps in this test: {{ item.steps }} <br>
        Test description: {{ item.description }}
        </p>
      </template>
   </template>
  </template>

  <script>
    var template = document.querySelector('template[is="auto-binding"]');
    template.count=0;
    template.myArray = [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Name 1",
        "active": false,
        "steps": 3,
        "description": "Lorem"
      },{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Name 2",
        "active": true,
        "steps": 4,
        "description": "Ipsum"
      },{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Name 3",
        "active": true,
        "steps": 5,
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum"
      }
    ];
</script>
```

Then you get the output you want:

```
Item id:2 is active! 
Amount of steps in this test: 4 
Test description: Ipsum

Item id:3 is active! 
Amount of steps in this test: 5 
Test description: Lorem Ipsum
```

The Plunker is http://plnkr.co/edit/nBYeeZ2Uw0EFihAhNYpl?p

Comment: The problem is that this would require me to write a filter for every property? My actual objects have more than 10 properties, which I all need to access somewhere, like showing the price, results, steps, ... Also, the filter I included does work, but I don't know if I can access the object properties without having to make additional filters.

Comment: With only one filter you can filter using as much properties as you want. Could you please describe me an example of what you want and I'll code it :)

Comment: Well currently I have the id as an index of an array so I can do `<template if="{{myArray[id].active}}">` to easily in one line check a property of an object. Or I can also easily show other data: `Amount of steps in this test: {{myArray[id].steps}}`, `Test description: {{myArray[id].description}}`, etcetera.

Comment: You can use the `repeat` to iterate through your array, and then your filters: 
```
    <template repeat="{{item in myArray}}">
       <template if="{{ item.active }}">
       Amount of steps in this test {{ item.steps }}
      </template>
   </template>
  </template>

Comment: I've edited my answer and done a new example, more according to what I've understood in your comments. What about it now?

Comment: I found a sort of workaround for my issue. I had a variable that had the index of the object in the array. Where I set this value, I use the filter I described to turn the `id` into this index. By doing this I don't need to get any properties directly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad you found your workaround! Thanks to you for the feedback :)